# Flickering Control on WinForm when changing location

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I made a really easy game, in which a Pacman chases your mouspointer.
But every time it changes its Location, the pacMan - Panel with a image on it flickers.

```
private void Move_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int newPositionX = pacMan.Location.X;
    int newPositionY = pacMan.Location.Y;

    lblMousX.Text = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X.ToString();
    lblMouseY.Text = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y.ToString();
    lblThingX.Text = pacMan.Location.X.ToString();
    lblThingY.Text = pacMan.Location.Y.ToString();

    if (pacMan.Location.X + 15 < PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X)
    {
        newPositionX = pacMan.Location.X + 1;
        if (pacMan.BackgroundImage != Properties.Resources.Pac_Rechts)
            pacMan.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Pac_Rechts;
    }
    if (pacMan.Location.X + 15 > PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X)
    {
        newPositionX = pacMan.Location.X - 1;
        if (pacMan.BackgroundImage != Properties.Resources.Pac_Links)
            pacMan.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Pac_Links;
    }
    if (pacMan.Location.Y + 15 < PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y)
    {
        newPositionY = pacMan.Location.Y + 1;
        if (pacMan.BackgroundImage != Properties.Resources.Pac_Unten)
            pacMan.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Pac_Unten;
    }
    if (pacMan.Location.Y + 15 > PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y)
    {
        newPositionY = pacMan.Location.Y - 1;
        if (pacMan.BackgroundImage != Properties.Resources.Pac_Oben)
            pacMan.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Pac_Oben;
    }

    pacMan.Location = new Point(newPositionX, newPositionY);
}
```

I already set "DoubleBuffered" to true but that didn't change anything.

How can I remove that flickering?

Comment: Id imagine the problem is more your draw routine.

Comment: Can you describe that a bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the Problem...

You have to change the Panel to a PictureBox.

Answer (score 0):

Create a child to the Panel and add to the constructor this code:

```
this.SetStyle(
            System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer,
            true);
```

Had this problem already...